# How to open the default android browser without specifying an URL?

Tags: android

I'm loosing my mind over this. I want to open the user's default web browser. I can use this:

```
startActivity( new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://google.com")));
```

To open the browser and send the user to that URL. But I don't want to send him to a specific URL, I just want to open the browser. I'm sure it's a simple solution, I just can't find it. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To just open the browser without any URL opened you can use

```
startActivity( new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("about:blank")));
```

Comment: Yeah that's good but the problem with that is that... for example in a browser like Dolphin it opens a blank page. I would like it to open the default SpeedDial page

Comment: ah okay, I see the point - you should probably add that to your question, that makes things clearer

Answer (score 3):

After a bunch of searching, I was able to do this:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
Intent queryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
ActivityInfo af = queryIntent.resolveActivityInfo(pm, 0);
Intent launchIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
launchIntent.setClassName(af.packageName, af.name);
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

It basically says "What application would handle this?". Then it grabs that applications package and class name then fires an intent for the main action.