# How to call browser not default one?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments

I am creating application in android here i want to call browser not default one but specific one like opera or someone else... Frankly speaking these browsers better than default one and also having more options..

I googled lot but i could able to get only to call default browser.

Here is code for call default browser

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.co.in"));

startActivity(intent);
```

Pls any suggestion ...

Comment: Why do you need to call a specific browser? Why not let the system launch the user's default? They probably won't appreciate having their choice overridden. Also, how will you handle the situation where the browser you want is not installed?

Comment: oh i never think in this way ... So its better to let the sys launch the users default.. thnx @eldarerathis

Answer (score 1):

Use WebView,
For example,
In xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

In java

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

    }

}
```

In manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: i ll try and let u know thnx buddy

Answer (score 1):

Please see:
[Android launch browser without specifying a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421897/android-launch-browser-without-specifying-a-url/20490335#20490335)

There you will find the code to *getDefaultBrowserComponent()*; the *getNonDefaultBrowserComponent()* will be an easy exercise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Intent.setClassName() property before calling the startActivity() method. You have to specify package name and activity of your browser app.